Sample output of diffuse BSDF with pixelated texture coordinates
I'm not sure the title of this question really makes sense.
Basically what I'm trying to do is create pixelated lighting from the output of a Diffuse BSDF + Shader to RGB, so that the pixels are aligned with the surface of the mesh rather than being aligned with the camera.
An example of what I'm not trying to do. This scene is pixelated in the compositor, and the pixels are aligned with the camera view.

Using the nodes below I can create pixelated(?) coordinates, but I don't know how to apply these to the output from the Diffuse BSDF + Shader to RGB nodes

In this case I just used it to make a pixelated voronoi texture

This is an example of what I'd like to do. In this case I just baked the lighting and the pixelated the texture manually. The compression kind of destroys it, but you can see pretty well in the shadow on the plane how it's pixelated.

As TheLabCat suggested I tried reducing shadow settings, both in the light object properties and scene render properties, but I couldn't get something really looked like the baked lighting.

Here is a better image showing what it should like:


I cannot tell what you are trying to do. Do you have any examples?

@TheLabCat I have added an example of what I'm trying to do.

Use the ray portal to sample only the "center" of each pixel.

@Leander I have no idea what that means and I’ve been using Blender since 2.78, you’ve gotta be more clear.

These look like low quality buffer shadows, but atm I’m having difficulty turning the EEVEE shadow quality down. I can’t tell if it’s a bug or there’s a setting I don’t know about.

@TheLabCat The ray portal node only exists since half a year though. Check my answer.

@Leander you didn’t have to be sarcastic, but that aside I do see that I’ve fallen behind.

Oh, honestly I didn't try to be unfriendly. What I wanted to convey was: "The ray portal node only exists since have a year though, so even if you are experienced in most of the features, it would be possible that you have missed this feature since it is fairly new." - But I agree, that it does not sound polite even when paraphrased. Sorry, I will sincerely try to put more focus on more open and kind phrasing. - Wow, even that could sound sarcastic... I'll try to add some emoticon to lighten the tone: =)

You can create a rasterized look using the ray portal node.
Add an extra layer of geometry to your object (in my case a plane) and the vertices slight along the normal axis. (It should be possible to use displacement in the shader.) Make it only visible to the camera (invisible to all other rays).
Then sample the position (Geometry Node) and convert it to discrete values (for example using the Math>Round Node.
Shoot the Ray Portal along the normal to sample the surface below it.

The advantage of the ray portal node is that you will be free to adjust the pixels to any sample position freely and find artistic workarounds for any type of geometry. The disadvantage is, that it is very slow.
